# MPICH2 smpd version mismatch

Tags: mpi, mpich

After I installed MPICH2, I checked the location of smpd by "smpd -get binary" commands. It returns "C:\Program Fils\MATLAB2009a\bin\win32\smpd.exe". So my program doesn't point out smpd in MPICH2.

How can I solve this problem? I already try to change path in system variable and move it in front of MATLAB path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply go to MPICH2/bin folder and command at cmd "smpd -install" solves the problem